# Roku - HTTP redirect url inside poster not working

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

If I set the uri field of a poster node with a HTTP redirection url, I am facing trouble getting the image loaded. **Does Roku poster node support HTTP redirects?**

Poster is loading if I use a direct image link anyways. The issue seems to be there only for a HTTP redirection url.

Does anyone been through this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Poster node does not support using HTTP redirects. There is not much you can do with the Poster node beyond setting the URI and waiting to see whether or not it loads the image. Even setting an observer on the loadStatus of the Poster node yielded no helpful information in this case.